# Tareas asíncronas en Javascript y PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

tengo un proyecto donde uso: (JavaScript, JQuery, PHP, PostgreSQL). Quiero implementar la tareas asíncronas y colocar la animaciones con progress-bar, pero no sé por donde empezar, porque nunca lo he hecho en estos lenguajes.

Dejo mí código del Login para tener una idea de cómo lo podría usar para logearme.

JS:

```
    function iniciarSesion() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById("txtusuario").value;
    var clave = document.getElementById("txtclave").value;

    var datos = {
        "usuario": usuario,
        "clave": clave
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "./model/usuario.php?dato=leerusuario",
        type: 'POST',
        data: datos,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (respuesta) {
            if (respuesta.usuario === usuario) {
                var pagina = "http://localhost/BERLINUXERP/index.php";
                document.location.href = pagina;
            } else {
                $('#alertclaveinvalida').show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

PHP

```
switch ($variable) {
case "leerusuario":

    $pdo = Database::connect();

    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $preclave = $_POST['clave'];

    $clave = md5($preclave);

    $sql = " SELECT u_alias, u_nombre, u_clave, r_nombre, r_clase, rp_id, rp_nombre "
            . " FROM usuario, rol_x_usuario, roles, rol_padre "
            . " WHERE u_alias = :usuario AND u_clave = :clave AND "
            . "  rxu_usuario = u_alias AND r_id = rxu_rol AND rxu_permitido = TRUE AND r_id != 1 AND rp_id = r_padre
                 ORDER BY rp_id ";

    $info = array();
    $roles = array();
    $usuarioEncontrado = false;

    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindParam(":clave", $clave, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->execute();

    $resultado = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($resultado as $row) {
        if ($usuarioEncontrado == false) {
            session_start();
            $info['usuario'] = $row['u_alias'];
            $info['clave'] = $row['u_clave'];
            $info['nombre'] = $row['u_nombre'];

            array_push($roles, array("rol" => $row['r_nombre'],
                "clase" => $row['r_clase'],
                "rol_padre_id" => $row['rp_id'],
                "rol_padre" => $row['rp_nombre']));

            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['u_nombre'];
            $_SESSION['alias'] = $row['u_alias'];

            $usuarioEncontrado = true;
        } else {
            array_push($roles, array("rol" => $row['r_nombre'],
                "clase" => $row['r_clase'],
                "rol_padre_id" => $row['rp_id'],
                "rol_padre" => $row['rp_nombre']));
        }
    }

    if ($usuarioEncontrado) {
        $_SESSION['roles'] = $roles;
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);
    }

    Database::disconnect();
    echo json_encode($info);
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
```

Comment: de preferencia, no indiques la ruta directamente en la respuesta del ajax, ´var pagina = "http://localhost/BERLINUXERP/index.php";´ mejor manda como respuesta tu ruta

Comment: Traté de agregar esto: header("Location: login.php"); dentro del último if del PHP pero no redirecciona, me tocó dejarlo así para que de momento funcionara, pero ese no es el caso con tiempo lo arreglaré, quisiera agregar ahora los progress-bar con tareas asíncronas.

Comment: Revisa esto: https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/jQuery-Based-Progress-Button-For-Async-Functions-ProgressButton.html